# removing a file from root folder in cocoa mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Using removeItemAtPath ho to remove a file in root folder?
is there a way to get the user enter root password and then cocoa deletes the file

any ideas

Comment: Out of curiosity, what file in the root could you possibly want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Authorization Services for this. See the [Authorization Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) for full information on how to escalate privileges correctly.